# Steps to Clone an Azure Resource

Tags: azure, clone, development-environment

I have a very simple requirement to setup an Azure dev resource on the same subscription as the prod environment. This dev resource would be a 1 to 1 clone of a single Azure Datafactory resource.

Is there a way to simply clone the Azure DataFactory resource on the same subscription and rename it to a "...-dev" version?

(At present, I do not see a simple clone function...)

Answer (score 1):

There is no clone option, but you can [export the automation script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-export-template) and re-run that in order to replicate the resource. If you want to automate many similar deployments in Azure, look in to [ARM Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/).

Keep in mind data factory has two key aspects:

1. The actual Data Factory service instance
2. Your Data Factory pipelines (i.e. the data workflows you write in Data Factory)

Both can be automated and deployed using ARM Templates. (2) above can also be linked to source control where you can then clone and re-use the definition files.